# Datetime formatting in pandas .to_markdown()

Tags: python, pandas, markdown

I have a pandas DataFrame which has a column of dtype datetime:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Mock-up data
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                   'month': [2, 3],
                   'day': [4, 5]})
df = pd.to_datetime(df)

print(df)

# 0   2015-02-04
# 1   2016-03-05
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I would like to use the `.to_markdown()` method to display this DataFrame.

However, the `.to_markdown()` method displays the datetimes in scientific notation:

```py
print(df.to_markdown())

# |    |           0 |
# |---:|------------:|
# |  0 | 1.42301e+18 |
# |  1 | 1.45714e+18 |
```

Is there a way to have the `.to_markdown()` method display these dates in a
more human-readable manner? The `.to_latex()`, `.to_csv()`, and
`.to_string()` methods already behave this way:

```py
# Other .to_ methods behave as desired, eg.
print(df.to_latex())

# \begin{tabular}{ll}
# \toprule
# {} &          0 \\
# \midrule
# 0 & 2015-02-04 \\
# 1 & 2016-03-05 \\
# \bottomrule
# \end{tabular}
```

---

pandas version: 1.3.2

tabulate version: 0.8.9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood the `.to_markdown()` method uses the [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) package. The `floatfmt` named argument can be used to control the formatting of floats, but I cannot see how this could be useful here.

The best solution I can *currently find* is simply to format the datetime column as a column of strings before calling the `.to_markdown()` method:

```py
print(df.astype(str).to_markdown())

# |    | 0          |
# |---:|:-----------|
# |  0 | 2015-02-04 |
# |  1 | 2016-03-05 |
```

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the feature to format a timestamp is an open enhancement: https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/67

Until implemented, it works for me to (just) convert the timestamp column to text (similarly as @jwalton does it) if the data frame contains multiple columns:

```py
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda dt: dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
df.to_markdown()
```